# 'YAML syntax error: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1' while creating a GitHub issue form

Tags: github, templates, yaml, github-issues

I get the error `YAML syntax error: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1` while I've created another GitHub issue form.

Here is my code:

```yaml
name: Bug report
description: Send a bug WinUEFI has that needs to be fixed
title: "[BUG] <title>"
labels: [bug]
body:
- type: markdown
  attributes:
    value: |
      Thank you for filling out a bug that WinUEFI has! It helps me make the application better. Please be as detailed as possible so that i may consider and review the bug easier.
      I ask that you search all the issues to avoid a duplicate bug. If one exists, please reply if you have anything to add to it.
      Before requesting a bug, please make sure you are using the latest version and that the bug you are requesting is not already fixed in WinUEFI.                       
- type: textarea
  id: bug-and-suggestion-relation
  attributes:
    label: Is your bug related to a suggestion?
    description: Please give some context for this request. Why do you want it to be fixed?
  validations:
    required: true
- type: textarea
  id: bug-description
  attributes:
    label: Describe the bug
    description: A clear and concise description of what the bug is and what needs to be fixed.
  validations:
    required: true
 - type: textarea
   id: alternatives
   attributes:
     label: Describe alternatives you've considered
     description: List any alternatives you might have tried to fix the bug you want.
 - type: checkboxes
   id: agreements
   attributes:
     label: Agreements
     description: Please agree to the following:
   options:
     - label: I have searched for and ensured there isn't already an open issue regarding this.
       required: true
     - label: I have ensured the bug I'm reporting isn't already fixed in the latest supported WinUEFI build.
       required: true
 - type: textarea
   id: other
   attributes:
     label: Other
     description: Add any other context or screenshots about the feature request below.
```

EDIT: I have fixed it by correcting an another few things.

- - - I've tried changing the name value, but it did not help.
- - - I expected it to parse correctly and work as a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues going on with your YAML. First, `labels: [bug]` should be `labels: ["but"]` as that accepts a string array.

Second, you have a lot of issues with spacing. Remember that YAML is highly sensitive to spacing. Here is the working YAML of what you are looking for:

```yaml
name: Bug report
description: Send a bug WinUEFI has that needs to be fixed
title: "[BUG] <title>"
labels: ["bug"]
body:
  - type: markdown
    attributes:
      value: |
        Thank you for filling out a bug that WinUEFI has! It helps me make the application better. Please be as detailed as possible so that i may consider and review the bug easier.
        I ask that you search all the issues to avoid a duplicate bug. If one exists, please reply if you have anything to add to it.
        Before requesting a bug, please make sure you are using the latest version and that the bug you are requesting is not already fixed in WinUEFI.
        
  - type: textarea
    id: bug-and-suggestion-relation
    attributes:
      label: Is your bug related to a suggestion?
      description: Please give some context for this request. Why do you want it to be fixed?
    validations:
      required: true

  - type: textarea
    id: bug-description
    attributes:
      label: Describe the bug
      description: A clear and concise description of what the bug is and what needs to be fixed.
    validations:
      required: true

  - type: textarea
    id: alternatives
    attributes:
      label: Describe alternatives you've considered
      description: List any alternatives you might have tried to fix the bug you want.

  - type: checkboxes
    id: agreements
    attributes:
      label: Agreements
      description: "Please agree to the following:"
      options:
        - label: I have searched for and ensured there isn't already an open issue regarding this.
          required: true
        - label: I have ensured the bug I'm reporting isn't already fixed in the latest supported WinUEFI build.
          required: true

  - type: textarea
    id: other
    attributes:
      label: Other
      description: Add any other context or screenshots about the feature request below.
```

Comment: I edited my YAML and saw a few issues. Fixed that and it works now!